# FHIR Questionnaire.json (Flutter/Dart): How to access values and extension that have to be calculated first?

Tags: dart, hl7-fhir

Me:
absolute newbe to FHIR and Flutter/Dart.

My situation:
Our Flutter Web-Application is used by patients to answer the patient surveys we assign to them.
I have to modify this application to consume FHIR-Questionnaire.json's (replacing our proprietary data models), but I have to keep the whole structure (models, types and the backend) untouched. Therefore I have to read out the questionnaire-items and create instances of our own models (including the "answer"-objects) so the application can procceed as usual.

Problems I'm facing:
Some (nested) QuestionnaireItems have "enableWhen"'s and extension's and some extensions are looking like this:

```
"extension": [
    {
        "url": "http://hl7.org/fhir/uv/sdc/StructureDefinition/sdc-questionnaire-enableWhenExpression",
        "valueExpression": {
            "language": "text/fhirpath",
            "expression": "today() >= $resource.item.where(linkId = 'dateOfBirth').answer.valueDate + 10 years and today() <= $resource.item.where(linkId = 'dateOfBirth').answer.valueDate + 59 years"
        }
    }
],
```

This formula is used to make sure the question ("Have you ever given birth?") is only shown to women in their fertile years. Our old models provided a value like "fertile", "infant" or "general" we could check against.

It seems the Fhir-Framework is looking up the LinkId 'dateOfBirth' and computes everything it needs by itself to provide a valid result but I have no idea how to interpret the formula provided in dart to get a propper value - outside of the fhir-framework - I can use further on in our own types and models.

Question:
How can I get at least a true/false-value out of above formula?

obviously I have tried to create a Map<String, dynamic> out of the incoming Json and tried to get the formula, but I ran into problems even pulling it into a String-Variable ("waiting for Chrome-DevTools"... yeah, debugging with VSCode and Chrome aren't as easy as in VS Professional 2022).

I tried the walkFhirPath-Method provided by the FHIR_Path-Library (see: https://pub.dev/packages/fhir_path/versions/0.9.5) but I haven't found any example on how the required parameter "pathExpression" has to look like for my purpose.